slope of Tangent line perpendicular to line from origin does not equal the derivative
Slope of tangent line at theta=pi/3 and r=2-3cos(theta)
I tried finding the slope of the tangent line by using a perpendicular line from the origin and then finding its slope. However, the real answer using derivatives is $5\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ and when I reviewed my answer with my professor he didn't know what's wrong. This is in polar coordinates by the way. Picture is my solution.

Hello and welcome to MSE. You should avoid using links since they are not a reliable source, they can simply go down, and we are interested in preserving the questions for future reference.

The community also encourages you to employ using MathJax. That way, the question is typically clearer to understand and  visually more attractive.

In general, the line from the origin to a point on the curve is NOT going to be perpendicular to the tangent to the curve. There is only one curve, upto rescaling, for which the line from the origin is always going to be perpendicular to the tangent. This is not that curve.
